# Traefik in microk8s allways 404 trought HTTPS

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, traefik-ingress, microk8s

I deployed a microk8s single node cluster on a simple & small VPS.
At the moment I running without cert SSL (Traefik cert by default).
The http:80 version of ingress is working correctly, I can browse the webpages at the correct ingress from HTTP, but when I try to run in https, Traefik is showing a 404.

I appreciate it if anyone can help me.

Many thanks

This is my Traefik config & my ingress config.

Traefik:

```yaml
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: ingressroutes.traefik.containo.us

spec:
  group: traefik.containo.us
  version: v1alpha1
  names:
    kind: IngressRoute
    plural: ingressroutes
    singular: ingressroute
  scope: Namespaced

---
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: middlewares.traefik.containo.us

spec:
  group: traefik.containo.us
  version: v1alpha1
  names:
    kind: Middleware
    plural: middlewares
    singular: middleware
  scope: Namespaced

---
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: ingressroutetcps.traefik.containo.us

spec:
  group: traefik.containo.us
  version: v1alpha1
  names:
    kind: IngressRouteTCP
    plural: ingressroutetcps
    singular: ingressroutetcp
  scope: Namespaced

---
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: ingressrouteudps.traefik.containo.us

spec:
  group: traefik.containo.us
  version: v1alpha1
  names:
    kind: IngressRouteUDP
    plural: ingressrouteudps
    singular: ingressrouteudp
  scope: Namespaced

---
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: tlsoptions.traefik.containo.us

spec:
  group: traefik.containo.us
  version: v1alpha1
  names:
    kind: TLSOption
    plural: tlsoptions
    singular: tlsoption
  scope: Namespaced

---
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: tlsstores.traefik.containo.us

spec:
  group: traefik.containo.us
  version: v1alpha1
  names:
    kind: TLSStore
    plural: tlsstores
    singular: tlsstore
  scope: Namespaced

---
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: traefikservices.traefik.containo.us

spec:
  group: traefik.containo.us
  version: v1alpha1
  names:
    kind: TraefikService
    plural: traefikservices
    singular: traefikservice
  scope: Namespaced

---
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-controller

rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - services
      - endpoints
      - secrets
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - extensions
    resources:
      - ingresses
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - extensions
    resources:
      - ingresses/status
    verbs:
      - update
  - apiGroups:
      - traefik.containo.us
    resources:
      - middlewares
      - ingressroutes
      - traefikservices
      - ingressroutetcps
      - ingressrouteudps
      - tlsoptions
      - tlsstores
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch

---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-controller

roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: traefik-ingress-controller
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: traefik-ingress-controller
    namespace: default
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: traefik-ingress-controller

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: traefik
  labels:
    app: traefik

spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: traefik
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: traefik
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      # hostPort doesn't work with CNI, so we have to use hostNetwork instead
      # see https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23920
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
      hostNetwork: true
      serviceAccountName: traefik-ingress-controller
      containers:
      - name: traefik
        image: traefik:v2.2
        args:
          - --ping
          - --ping.entrypoint=http
          - --api.insecure
          - --accesslog
          - --entrypoints.web.Address=:80
          - --entrypoints.websecure.Address=:443
          #- --providers.kubernetescrd
          - --providers.kubernetesingress
          - forwardedHeaders.trustedIPs:["Public IP VPS running microk8s"]
          #- --certificatesresolvers.default.acme.tlschallenge
          #- --certificatesresolvers.default.acme.email=foo@you.com
          #- --certificatesresolvers.default.acme.storage=acme.json
          # Please note that this is the staging Let's Encrypt server.
          # Once you get things working, you should remove that whole line altogether.
          #- --certificatesresolvers.default.acme.caserver=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
        ports:
          - name: web
            containerPort: 80
          - name: websecure
            containerPort: 443
          - name: admin
            containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: traefik

spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      name: web
      port: 80
    - protocol: TCP
      name: admin
      port: 8080
    - protocol: TCP
      name: websecure
      port: 443
  selector:
    app: traefik
```

Ingress:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: front
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/redirect-permanent: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-temporary-redirect: "false"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-proxy-headers: "X-Forwarded-Proto: https"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: front-dev.mgucommunity.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: front
          servicePort: 80
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are missing  the entrypoint websecure [annotation](https://docs.traefik.io/routing/providers/kubernetes-ingress/#annotations) so that Traefik also works on port `443`

```yaml
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.entrypoints: web, websecure
```

Note that if you want to redirect all your traffic to HTTPS you would have to have this in your DaemonSet config:

```yaml
...
        - --entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=websecure
        - --entrypoints.websecure.http.tls.certResolver=default
....
```

This might help [a write up on how to use a K8s ingress with Traefik v2](https://ralph.blog.imixs.com/2020/04/05/traefik-v2-2-and-kubernetes-ingress/).

✌️

Comment: Thank you for your response. The annotation to add the websecure entrypoint is not working. By default, as I can see in the dashboard, the ingress has the two values. I tried to put but I has the same result. I worked the https with the annotation of Tls true, but in that case, the http entrypoint is stoping working. Finally, the best solution is your second part of the response: force redirection to https